# Facing issue while handling NameError in Python. Conflicting results

Tags: python, exception

Generally, when I use exception handling such as NameError, it works fine. But in the following code, it fails to do so. Why?

**Code:**

```py
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Instance initiated.")

def isMember(instance):
    try:
        return isinstance(instance, Foo)
    except NameError:
        print("No such member exists.")

a = Foo()
isMember(b)
```

gives the following output-

```
Instance initiated.
NameError: name 'b' is not defined
```

Correct output should be -

```
Instance initiated.
No such member exists.
```

Comment: `b` is evaluated before being passed to the method and this is when the NameError occurs so your method is not actually called.

Answer (score 1):

This is being terminated before it gets to the function. It is getting exception when interpreter reads `b`.
You can have clear idea if you use try catch while calling the function.

```
class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print("Instance initiated.")

def isMember(instance):
    try:
        return isinstance(instance, Foo)
    except NameError:
        print("No such member exists.")

a = Foo()
try:
    isMember(b)
except NameError:
    print("executed here")
```

Comment: @ArnabMukherjee can you provide an example of where it works for `ZeroDivisionError`?